# Spring boot deployed as WAR on tomcat, How to Externalize application.properties for different profiles(Dev,Test,Staging,Prod)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-java-config

I am in a scenario where I am deploying by spring boot as a WAR on tomcat. Here in this application I have application.properties which has database username/password , some URL which help in consuming rest services(urls vary depending on the environment). Now I need to get the DB credentials and URL's depending on the environment it is deployed to. how to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

On external container ex tomcat
You can pass configuration using Jndi variable in context.xml
This var override local property defined in application.properties

Or pass -Dspring.profiles.active=env
in tomcat startup script ,for select environment specific application.properties
if you prefer to have configuration inside the war

Comment: Question1: Can I get the location of my property files from tomcat's context.xml to spring @Resource

Question2: Do I need to  specify all content available in my application.properties to tomcat's context.xml and read them in Spring. Please suggest how to achieve this and appreciate if any one can provide working example/tutorial to do this

Answer (score 1):

As per [24. Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) it should be enough to place a profile specific properties e.g. `application-dev.properties` on the classpath. The property precedence is:

> ...
>
> 12. Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).
> 13. Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).
> 14. Application properties outside of your packaged jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
> 15. Application properties packaged inside your jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
>
> ...

This can however work slight differently if you are packaging as JAR as per [24.3 Application Property Files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files). The property precedence is:

> 1. A /config subdirectory of the current directory
> 2. The current directory
> 3. A classpath /config package
> 4. The classpath root

Comment: I want to place the files in tomcat/webapp folder so that system engineers can simply drop the file there and can easily move the war to different environments

Comment: Are you hosting multiple webapps in the same Tomcat and should they share the config?

Comment: No only one webapp. If I put various properties files say appliaction.dev.properties,application.test.properties,application.prod.properties on resources/config folder of the application then how application knows which env it is in. I am deploying app as WAR not as JAR and in external tomcat not embeded

Comment: Then it really doesn't matter how you will do it, `tomcat/config` dir is probably preferable but if I were you I'd repackage the app as runnable JAR instead of deploying to Tomcat.

Comment: its the requirement to deploy it to tomcat.
I had tried doing :
@PropertySource(value={"file:C:/Users/foo/apache-tomcat-8.5.28/webapps/application.properties}"})

this throws 404 error but if I copy the path from console and open it in windows explorer file is actually der at that location.

Comment: Yuck, a hard-coded full qualified path. Consider to use, at least, variables like _value={file:config.path}_ and pass the parameter via System properties, e.g. _-Dconfig.path=..._

Answer (score 1):

according to the discussion with Karol, I guess using properties sources referencing file system path should be ok:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("${mywebapp.config.dir}/application.properties")
public class SpringConfig {
}
```

And just path JVM args at the startup of tomcat like

```
-Dmywebapp.config.dir=file:/etc/mywebapp
```

This way you can deploy one application.properties different for each environment.

As for your comment:

@PropertySource(value={"file:C:/Users/foo/apache-tomcat-8.5.28/webapps/application.properties}"})

as it's a windows system path may you have to double backslash your path: C:\\Users\\foo ...

Answer (score 1):

I am able to read the properties file from tomcat/webapp location

for every environment I can ask system engineers to drop the file at the location,
I dont know if its a good solution. Please suggest

```
@PropertySource(value={"file:C:/Users/foo/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.5.28/webapps/application.properties"})
```